# Generate Blogposts using Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to generate simple Blog-Posts using Javascript. My function looks like this :

```
function generatePost(title, time, text) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "content";
    document.getElementById("postcontainer").appendChild(div);
}
```

If my function is used in the HTML-Document the structure should look like this:

```
<div id="postcontainer">
    <div class="content"> /*This is the actual post*/
        <h3>title<span>time</span></h3>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h3>title2<span>time2</span></h3>
        <p>text2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to be able to generate multiple posts without the classes/ids interrupting each other. Any idea ? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what do you mean by `interrupting each other`?

Comment: You shouldn't have `id`s on elements that are not unique to a page.  Give it a `class` of `postcontainer` instead.  "clashing" classes aren't invalid.

Comment: If I would add an id to the content-class-div, it wouldn't work with more than 1 div and if I would add the elements just to the classes, I would have as many headlines as posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/trjshpLo/2/) a very blunt solution. Adding an id to each content div which includes a unique post id. In this case, the post number.

```
var postCount = 0;

function generatePost(title, time, text) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "content";
    div.id = "blog_" + postCount
    postCount++;
   document.getElementById("postcontainer").appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that.